Extend already published C++ interface
I have an already published API that I want to extend with new functionalities, but I can't make it work.
The original (simplified) is something like this:
IMonitorManaged.h
#ifdef MONITORMANAGED_EXPORTS
#define MONITORMANAGED_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MONITORMANAGED_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif 

#include "IMonitorConfiguration.h"

class IMonitorManaged : public virtual IMonitorConfiguration
{
public:
    virtual ~IMonitorManaged() {}
    virtual bool Close() = 0;               
    virtual bool Initalize() = 0;
    virtual bool LoadMGConfiguration(const wchar_t* xmlConfigurationFile) = 0;
    virtual bool Record(bool active) = 0;
    virtual AssemblyVersion GetAssemblyVersion() = 0;           
};

extern "C" MONITORMANAGED_API Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IMonitorManaged* GetHardwareMonitor();
/**
 \brief Gets program monitor
 \returns   Null if it fails, else the program monitor.
 */
extern "C" MONITORMANAGED_API Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IMonitorManaged* GetProgramMonitor();


The Hardware and Program Monitor can be obtained with the only exported functions:
extern "C" MONITORMANAGED_API Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IMonitorManaged* GetHardwareMonitor();

extern "C" MONITORMANAGED_API Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IMonitorManaged* GetProgramMonitor();

These two interfaces are defined as follow in files "IProgramMonitorManaged.h"
and "IHardwareMonitorManaged.h"
class IHardwareMonitorManaged : public virtual IMonitorManaged
{
public:
    virtual ~IHardwareMonitorManaged() {}
    virtual bool SetPosition(const Point& position) = 0;    
};

class IProgramMonitorManaged : public virtual IMonitorManaged
{
public:

    virtual ~IProgramMonitorManaged() {}
    virtual bool SetProgramError(ProgramError error, const wchar_t* sourceId) = 0;
};

Who wants to use the API can use the "lib" or use directly the LoadLibrary() the get the reference and create the monitors:
#include "IProgramMonitorManaged.h"
#include "IHardwareMonitorManaged.h"

std::unique_ptr<Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IHardwareMonitorManaged> m_HwMonitor;
std::unique_ptr<Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IProgramMonitorManaged> m_ProgMonitor;

m_ProgMonitor.reset(dynamic_cast<IProgramMonitorManaged*>(GetProgramMonitor()));
m_HwMonitor.reset(dynamic_cast<IHardwareMonitorManaged*>(GetHardwareMonitor()));
auto res = m_HwMonitor->Initalize();
auto res2 = m_ProgMonitor->Initalize();

Everything works fine. Now I would like to extend the interface IMonitorManaged with a new interface "IDebug"
class IDebug
{
public:

    virtual ~IDebug() {}
    virtual Status ActivateLog(bool enable, const wchar_t* logFilePath) = 0;
};


So I modify the IMonitorManaged.h to:
class IMonitorManaged : public virtual IMonitorConfiguration, public virtual IDebug
{
public:
   virtual ~IMonitorManaged() {}
   virtual bool Close() = 0;               
   virtual bool Initalize() = 0;
   virtual bool LoadMGConfiguration(const wchar_t* xmlConfigurationFile) = 0;
   virtual bool Record(bool active) = 0;
   virtual AssemblyVersion GetAssemblyVersion() = 0;
};

So I simply add "public virtual IDebug" to the IMonitorManaged interface.
Now I want to update a customer with the new API version which has the new interface but also several bugs fixing. This customer has an already program which uses an old version of the API and we don't want to rebuild a new program to just solve the bug. As soon as I update the "API.dll" the final API consumer is still able to get the Hardware and Program monitor but when the method "AssemblyVersion GetAssemblyVersion()" is called the method Close() is actually executed and the program crash with:
System.AccessViolationException

Finally my question... How can I update and existing installation with a new API version that has both bug fixing and new implementation?
I would expect that the API consumer to use the new interfaces would cast the Hardware/ProgramMonitor to IDebug to check if the interface is available and use it only if not null. This works pretty fine in COM interfaces, I would expect the same also in pure c++.
Any hints?

Interesting. And your code certainly has a certain .NET flavoring to it. ;)
How do you link/load the dll ? With LoadLibrary() or statically ?
Please also check this out if it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208005/how-to-update-a-c-dll-without-needing-to-relink-the-exe-with-the-lib-file

"...Who wants to use the API can use the "tlb" or ..." are you mixing COM and direct C++ traversal of interfaces ?

@RichardCritten thank you for higlight the "tlb". I was actually mean LIB. Sorry for the wrong extension which created confusion. So I don't mix COM and direct c++, it's only c++

@nick I tried both using LoadLibrary("Api.dll") and using the tlb in the linker. But the result is the same

The error you describe suggests that the vtbl entries in the new library do not match the vptr entries in the consumer application. So the consumer will need to recompile their program against the modified header file.

@OldBoy do you have best practice to avoid this? Do you think there is a way to guarantee compatibilty with old version?

Extending a class in C++ is not the same as doing similar in COM. In COM you can add a new function without problems, since any consumer must do a lookup before using the function. And the lookup is handled by the COM provider. In C++ much of the work happens at compile time (building tables etc.) so you cannot gurantee the exact same structure. And by adding IDebug you have effectively created a totally different class to the one currently in use.

Extending interfaces without breaking ABI is possible but very hard and depends on the specific compiler used, perhaps Instead of extending the interface you can extend the object itself to have both interfaces, dynamic casts between interfaces is possible, if i have IMonitorManaged i can dynamic cast it to IDebug if the base object inherits both then it will succeed, you can have your new interface called IMonitorManaged2 which inherits from the IDebug and your object will inherit both interfaces, this must work on any compiler.

@AhmedAEK so your suggestion is to create a new IMonitorManager which inherits from IMonitorManged and IDebug? And then expose a new method to get it:
extern "C" MONITORMANAGED_API Metrostaff::Statistic::Monitor::Managed::IMonitorManaged2* GetHardwareMonitor2();
Correct?

Yes, that's what microsoft has been doing for decades now with its interfaces, just create a new interface with a slightly different name.

yea, alternative would be redesignign the API to do something similar to what COM+ or Qt Framework are doing, which involves metadata stored in some standartized way instead of relying on vtable.

@AhmedAEK This. MS does it for DirectX all the time via adding 1, 2, 3, etc to the member function name, class name, enum, etc that inherits where possible from the previous version.

class IMonitorManaged : public virtual IMonitorConfiguration, public virtual IDebug
{
public:
   virtual ~IMonitorManaged() {}
   virtual bool Close() = 0;               
   virtual bool Initalize() = 0;
   virtual bool LoadMGConfiguration(const wchar_t* xmlConfigurationFile) = 0;
   virtual bool Record(bool active) = 0;
   virtual AssemblyVersion GetAssemblyVersion() = 0;
};

The above is a shortcut for inheritence.  You are implicitly relying on how the layout of the class is implemented by the compiler.
The compiler can see one class definition, and that class has to offer the virtual inheritance of IMonitorConfiguration, and IDebug.
The compiler may happen to choose a compatible layout to the new IMonitorManaged, but it has no obligation.
You actually need to keep the old and the new class definitions visible, and defined.
class IMonitorManaged2 : public {virtual} IMonitorManaged, public virtual IDebug
{
public:
};

This new class offers the improved interface, and because it inherits from IMonitorManaged, offers compatibility with IMonitorManaged.  Code which is expecting the old layout, will see due to the inheritance from the old layout.
